blank screen after reboot
I have a very plain system that was running 22.10.  Yesterday it offered to do a rather mundane looking update.  When the update completed it said that a reboot was required, I accepted and the box rebooted. It showed the normal bios screen, and the normal couple lines about the disk being clean... and then just presented a blank, black screen.  I let it sit over night, but still blank screen.  Pushed the reset button, same thing.  The box does seem to be running, it has a raid that is accessible.  Tried to use remote system, connection refused.  Telnet - connection refused.
How do I get a screen, any screen to come up?

Ubuntu 22.10 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/07/27/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-end-of-life-reached-on-july-20-2023/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Firstly I'd check what you're actually running, as if you're running Ubuntu 22.10 as you state, there have been NO UPDATES in some time so your system (being left unsupported & unmaintained as your details indicate) may have been altered. If you're running a supported system then correct your question, but using an unsupported and EOL system online isn't wise.   Also note that 22.10 release-upgrades are no longer possible; as that release had a upgrade path which is gone due EOL

@guiverc - well that's not much help. You're right, since I can't see anything about the system it might not be 22.10... it is a relatively recent release, and the problem happened after applying an update... but that's not really the problem.  At this point I'd love to update the system, but how can I do that when all it presents is a blank screen?

If it was me I'd boot live media and then navigate to your installed system and actually look what it is.... If it's as you state 22.10, then there have been no updates since July 2023 & your system may have been taken over & thus your issue is worse than you realize. (ie. you were tricked into applying false updates!)...  Alternatively if you're using 23.10 you have a rather different situation we can actually help you with... but knowing what you're using & what your actual problem is actually matters... Your details as provided imply you've been hacked! due to use of EOL system online

Alternatives to live system exist (eg. telling your system to stop at runlevel 1...), but again you didn't provide clear details as to what you're running (Server? Desktop?) and details highlight an EOL system we don't provide support for anyway...   If this is a production system I'd expect an operator to know what it is running, so go ask the machine operator (whomever is managing it; they need to do a better job & ensure it's not left unmaintained & using EOL software for starters!)

@guiverc - the system is a desktop that I use as a file server.  The "machine operator" is a bit of a goof, and I will properly chastise him next time I see him and well, that'd be me.
I'm clearly not an expert, I'm just an old retired guy that wrote a sh*t-ton of C programs back on a PDP-11/70 and rather be on a UNIX-like system than any Windows box.  All my systems are behind a hardware filewall and VPN so I feel pretty confident it hasn't been hacked.  Is there a chance I'm mis-remembering what release the box is on?  You bet.  The actual release just isn't that important to me

The release may not be important to you, but it provides useful details about your system; and your release details show no upgrades having existed for nearly a year due to EOL... which shows something is very wrong, hacked... or at least very non-standard...   The release also gives details as to software that make up your software stack (and clues as to what packages could have been updated; none since July 2023 for 22.10?? from official sources)... I used PDP-8, PDP-11 long ago too, but don't see how that relates. EOL software is off-topic on this site; SE Unix & Linux allows it.

@guiverc - as I've tried to explain - I have no user interface into the system of any sort.  No gui that would normally start, no telnet, no ssh - so I have no idea what release the box is on. It was getting updates, so I find it much more likely that it was on 22.04 LTS than it had been hacked.

@guiverc
What I was hoping to get was someone's idea how to do something to get  any sort of UI.  I freely admit I do not know much about administration of the box.  I thought this site, Ask Ubuntu, was here to  give me some useful guidance, you know - provide some actual help and not just keep telling my the release is EOL so too bad.
I'd be happy to give you or anyone more details about the system - if you tell me how I'm supposed to do that without any sort of interface into the system.

I already stated what I'd do... ie. I'd boot a live system (Ubuntu install media, using the TRY option available on Ubuntu Desktop for example; or other media that will run live) then "navigate to your installed system and actually look what it is"  ... ie. even if you're not familiar with Ubuntu, treat it like it's a generic POSIX, or Unix system;  /var/log/installer/ will contain details of install media, /var/log/dist-upgrade of ... etc or you can just view /etc/os-release to see details of what is installed etc.. THOUGH DON'T FORGET TO EXPLORE INSTALLED SYSTEM not live!

@guiverc - Okay, the existing system is 22.04 LTS (hence the updates).  My concern now is that I downloaded 24.04 used etcher to create the usb then booted it.  After multiple attempts to install, it gets to one of the first 4 steps, then just stops.  I flashed to 23.10 and tried, it worked up to the point that the choice was to erase the disk or create a new partition...  Isn't there an option to update in place?  Like what happens when I do it on-line.  I'm downloading a new copy of 24.04 and will try that
